# Why does using $('ul li').html inside a loop work differently from it's equivalent in vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I don't understand why $('selector').html() works differently from document.querySelectorAll when used inside a loop. I'm asking this question because I believe the answer might make me understand closures better.

Say I have a HTML file with an unordered list containing 3 empty list items.

```
<ul>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
</ul>
```

Next I want to insert some values inside the list items using a ascending loop and jQuery like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    $('ul li').html(i); /// Output: all list items are filled with 2
  }
})
```

All list items now contain "2" which is not what I expected. I was expecting 0, 1, 2.

Next I also tried the same thing in JS and the output was different

```
window.onload = function () {
  let list = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    list[i].innerHTML = i; //Output: 0 1 2
  }
}
```

In order to find a fix for the jQuery version on my code I checked the MDN section on closures and found this fix:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    $('ul li').html(foo(i)); /// output: 0 1 2
  }

  function foo(n) {
    return function bar(n) {
      return n;
    }
  }
})
```

Even if this works at the moment, I would like to know why does using the $().html() work differently from the plain JS example?

Comment: `$('ul li')` returns __all__ items that fit the selector.

Comment: `$('selector').` is selecting every possible element, when the loop finishes it is 2 in every `<li>`

Comment: Why I typed 'selector' in the title I was generally referring to any selector. The exact selector is not relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that with `$('ul li').html(`, you're always selecting *all* `ul li`s and setting the HTML of *all* of them. On the first iteration, you're setting *all* `ul li`s `innerHTML` to `0`. On the second iteration, you're setting *all* of their `innerHTML` to 1. By the end, all of their `innerHTML` is 2. You'd need to iterate over the `$('ul li')` collection instead:

```js
const lis = $('ul li');
for (let i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  $(lis[i]).html(i); /// output: 0 1 2
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

When you call `.html` with a *function*, jQuery calls that function with the *index of the current element being iterated over*, and assigns the return value to the innerHTML of that element.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  $('ul li').html(foo(i)); /// output: 0 1 2
}

function foo(n) {
  return function bar(n) {
    return n;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('ul li').html(i);` selects **all** items that fit selector (in your case - all `li`) and sets their html to `i`. On first iteration html is set to `0`, then to `1` and finally to `2`.

Equivalent for:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    list[i].innerHTML = i; //Output: 0 1 2
}
```

is

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    $('ul li').eq(i).html(i);
}
```